# Using the mingw-w64 fork with the standard msys

Tags: c++, windows, gnu, msys, mingw-w64

I want to use GNU GCC on Windows so I've downloaded mingw, but the x86_64 fork.

Instead of using cmd, I want to use msys, but msys is designed for the standard 32bits version of minGW. I've moved the bin, lib, libexec etc folders from minGW-64 to the msys folder, combining folder if necessary.

I didn't need to modify my PATH and msys console recognize the gcc executables.

I'm wondering what could be the drawbacks (if any) of using a msys prepared for the 32bits version of minGW. I'm afraid that may be using a not optimized environment and that I could discover that at link time I may be linking 32bits symbols or using 32bits symbols at runtime instead of being full 64.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `cmd`? (I use mingw-w64 regularly myself, but have never worked with msys, so maybe this is a silly question...)

Comment: MSYS: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/MSYS-1.0.11.exe/download?use_mirror=colocrossing  I used that and at the very end, it asks you to select your mingw folder location. I selected the x64 folder and everything works fine. It builds x32 and x64 libs. You can specify -m32 for 32 only and -m64 for 64 only.

Comment: @Cameron probably because `cmd` is such an **awful** shell. Its history behavior is insane, batch scripting is insane, the list goes on.

Comment: When migrating to Windows, tipically you'll have your sets of GNUmakefiles or autotools already done for other targets, and you just want to put them to work and not rewrite them. Hence, the need for msys. Cygwin would do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1):

There a bit of confusing terminology here:

The mingw-w64 *project* worked on getting 64-bit support on Windows. However, the result of their efforts is *both* a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version. You should not be using the classic mingw at all, since it is horribly outdated.

Comment: I don't care if along with a pure64 bits library I get a pure 32 library. Im scare however that with this approach I may end up getting a  mix of 64/32 symbols in the 64b same libs, for using a minGW 64 and a 32bits environment.